# How to customize allure report title and logo

Tags: allure

Below attached allure report image that generated via allure. Would like to customize report title and logo (image highlighted yellow) with my own title and logo instead of ALLURE REPORT and default logo. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To change the logo you should put the custom-logo-puglin into the puglins folder:

[image]

Edit the styles.css file and change the image reference to your own file.

In the jenkins to customize each project the plugins folder is placed here:

[image]

If you would like change for all the projects the folder is:

[image]

I recommend you the [user manual](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/)

Comment: How would you customize an Allure report that is integrated into Jenkins?  I don't see the same file structure as your screenshot.

Comment: The projects are placed into the hide .jenkins -> workspace -> projectname -> .allure  I'm going to add the image to my answer

Answer (score 5):

**Title Change**

I have changed the  title by cloning the repository from git and built a local copy. (I am using Windows OS).

Prerequisite

1. Gradle Version 5.2.1-https://gradle.org/releases/
2. Node Js-https://nodejs.org/en/download/ -npm -6.4.1

After installing prerequisite please follow below steps

1. Visit https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2
2. Clone the repository- Link:
   https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2.git
3. Assume the repository is saved locally under C:\allure2-2.10.0
4. Navigate to
   C:**\allure2-2.10.0\allure-generator\src\main\java\io\qameta\allure\summary**
5. Edit `SummaryPlugin.Java` file with any text editor
6. Search for `setReportName("Allure Report")`; and change to whatever name
   you want to give. Example setReportName("Automation Report")and save that file
7. Navigate to C:**\allure2-2.10.0\allure-generator**
8. Open command prompt (cmd) from this folder.Type **gradle build** and hit enter
9. Wait for few mins till it builds. It takes around 20 mins.
10. Navigate to `c:\allure2-2.10.0\allure-generator\build\libs`
11. Copy newly created file in build\libs folder `allure-generator-2.10.0.jar` file
12. I have installed manually from   https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_manual_installation
13. Navigate to **allure-2.10.0\allure-2.10.0\lib** and **override  allure-generator-2.10.0.jar file** with the file created newly from the gradle build folder

[Title change image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luubl.png)

---

**Logo Change**

1. I have installed manually from
   https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_manual_installation
2. Navigate to folder `allure-2.10.0\allure-2.10.0\config`
3. With any text editor edit file named **allure.yml**
4. At the last add one more line i.e.
   `- custom-logo-plugin` and save the file to activate the plugin. [allure.yml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qeYJ.png)
5. Navigate to `allure-2.10.0\plugins\custom-logo-plugin\static` edit
   styles.css

   ```
   .side-nav__brand {
   background: url('yourlogo.svg') no-repeat left center !important;
   padding-left: 180px !important;
   margin-left: 10px;
   }
   ```
6. In the same folder put your svg file or png image file
7. Now generate allure report.
8. Both title and logo will be changed according to your needs.

Hope it helps! Thanks

Comment: Thank you Suhas. it's working for me too.. Really appreciate your time and support.

Comment: Edited the style.css with the below option,

`.side-nav__brand {
  background: url('health care.png') no-repeat left center !important;
  margin-left: 3px;
  height: 40px;
  Background-size: contain !important;
}
.side-nav__brand span{
  display: none
}
.side-nav__brand:after{
  content: "Quality Gate Report";
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  block-size: fit-content;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  Margin-left: 3px;
}`

Answer (score 2):

In the custom-logo-plugin/static/styles.css add "!important" to the background style. With that change the custom-logo-plugin should work. This replaces only the logo image.

You can also use a logo-with-text by using "display:none" to .side-nav__brand-text selector and adding a height to .side-nav__brand selector. Your logo in this case should be 170px width.

Answer (score 0):

allure custom logo and report name / title plugin(s) are currently not working due to previous changes, you can achieve this goal by cloning the source, modifying it and building a local copy instead and using it until we fix such plugins or offer a new alternative.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.I'm just new to this..appreciate if you can send me the references.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation it is working with out problems customize the Allure logo

Answer (score 0):

I may answer a little late...

Concerning the report title, actually it seems to be hardcoded during the generation step.
Take a look at the files in "allure-generator/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/summary", 
especially SummaryPlugin.java
[SummaryPlugin.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkXa.png)

A short term solution could consist in editing the file "allure-report/widgets/summary.json" between "allure generate" and "allure open".
[summary.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghpUT.png)

The long term one should be to add a parameter during the generation step.